# Regular expression to check for content type application/json etc

Tags: javascript, regex

This particular application is returning `content-type` headers in the format `application/json;charset=UTF-8`

I'm not sure if this could change and get reduced to 'application/json' only or may be if I reuse this code somewhere else for?

My code is

`response.headers['Content-Type'].match(/text\/application//json/i)`

How to best check for content type application/json???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `RegExp` `/application\/json/`

```js
var response = {"Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8"};
console.log(response["Content-Type"].match(/application\/json/)[0]);
```

Comment: I am not sure that the [0] part is required. If no match, it will return null so parsing the first item of the array should throw an error.

Comment: This will not work for `application/geo+json`

Answer (score 3):

There are many json content types that don't begin with application/json.
See [24 of them here](https://webconcepts.info/concepts/media-type/).
One example is `application/geo+json`

The regex `/application\/[^+]*[+]?(json);?.*/` captures all of those and the vanilla `application/json` with or without charset information.

It works for:

```
application/json
application/json; charset=UTF-8
application/json-patch+json
application/geo+json
```

Per:

```js
console.log("application/json".match(/application\/[^+]*[+]?(json);?.*/)[1])
console.log("application/json; charset=UTF-8".match(/application\/[^+]*[+]?(json);?.*/)[1])
console.log("application/json-patch+json".match(/application\/[^+]*[+]?(json);?.*/)[1])
console.log("application/geo+json".match(/application\/[^+]*[+]?(json);?.*/)[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing right, You can check this using regex . If it returns null then it means it is not json.

```
if (response.headers['Content-Type'].match(/application\/json/i)){

   // do your stuff here
}
```

Other way is to find `application/json` string in header string

```
if (response.headers['Content-Type'].contains('application/json')){

   // do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[There are multiple `JSON` content-types.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/5922757) Not all of them are "official", but if you are trying to match them all, try [this regex](http://scriptular.com/#%5E((application%5C%2Fjson)%7C(application%5C%2Fx-javascript)%7C(text%5C%2Fjavascript)%7C(text%5C%2Fx-javascript)%7C(text%5C%2Fx-json))(%3B%2B.*)*%24%7C%7C%7C%7Cg%7C%7C%7C%7C%5B%22application%2Fjson%22%2C%22application%2Fjson%3Bcharset%3DUTF-8%22%2C%22application%2Fx-javascript%22%2C%22text%2Fjavascript%22%2C%22text%2Fx-javascript%22%2C%22text%2Fx-json%22%5D):

```
^((application\/json)|(application\/x-javascript)|(text\/javascript)|(text\/x-javascript)|(text\/x-json))(;+.*)*$
```

You can add / delete content types from the regex, just remember to put proper parenthesis around them.

Comment: A better refactoring would be `^(application\/(json|x-javascript)|text\/(x-)?javascript|x-json)(;.*)?$`.  The slashes don't need to be escaped for the regex to be correct, but if your language uses slashes as regex separators, you do need the backslashes for that reason.